# Run selenium webdriver via powershell on ubuntu?

Tags: powershell, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

Made a Powershell script, which is using Selenium webdriver, and it's currently running from an Windows machine.

I'm now looking to change from running the script on Windows, to instead be using a Ubuntu distro.

As I'm now (on Windows) using .NET dll's in the code to get Selenium started I need to find alternative language for this on Ubuntu. That's also compatible with Powershell.

Wondering if there's any such alternative for Powershell?

Comment: Have you looked into PowerShel Core?

Comment: Yeah, what I'm asking is if there's a way to use Powershell core on Ubuntu with Selenium webdriver.

Comment: you can try Mono

Comment: Ah Mono, would never have thought of that.Thanks Corey I'll give it a try!